# Slickgrid: Forcing the Grid to Reload

Tags: slickgrid

I have a grid,

```
 grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", loader.data, columns, options);
```

How do I get the grid to reload?  I'm using a remote model as by the examples as provided by the slickgrid documentation.

I want to force the reload based on clicking a button.

Thanks

Comment: Means you want to populate the grid with new data or just want to refresh the grid?

Comment: I want to populate the grid with new data.

Comment: Have a look at my ansmwer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644478/resetting-slickgrid-for-new-data/17723454#17723454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem.

I'm using the remotemodel from Slickgrid's examples.  The problem I had was I did not "clear()" the data.  The "clear()" function deleted all of the old data it contained.  I then invalidated and everything worked.

Comment: Does clear() really works as I was facing same issue but unable to resolve it with above solution.